# how does reduce or inject work in this code

Tags: ruby, reduce, inject, hash-of-hashes

Found this on code wars as one of the solutions. Can someone explain to me how "args.reduce(self)" works in this code; the block after makes sense.

```
config = { :files => { :mode => 0x777 }, :name => "config" }

class Hash
  def get_value( default, *args )
    args.empty? ? default : args.reduce(self) { |acum, key| acum.fetch(key) } rescue default
  end
end

config.get_value("", :files,:mode)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose we execute

```
{ :a=>{:b=>{:c=>3 } } }.get_value(4, :a, :b, :c)
```

so that within the method

```
default #=> 4
args    #=> [:a, :b, :c]
self    #=> { :a=>{:b=>{:c=>3 } } }
```

We then execute the following<sup>1</sup>:

```
args.empty? ? default : args.reduce(self) { |acum, key| acum.fetch(key) } rescue default
  #=> [:a, :b, :c].empty? ? 4 : [:a, :b, :c].reduce({ :a=>{:b=>{:c=>3 } } }) { |acum, key|
  #     acum.fetch(key) } rescue 4
  #=> 3
```

If `args #=> [:a, :b]`, we execute the following:

```
[:a, :b].empty? ? 4 : [:a, :b].reduce({ :a=>{:b=>{:c=>3 } } }) { |acum, key|
  acum.fetch(key) } rescue 4
  #=> {:c=>3}
```

If `args #=> [:a, :b, :cat]`, then a `KeyError` exception is raised and the inline `rescue` returns the value of `default`:

```
[:a, :b, :cat].empty? ? 4 : [:a, :b, :cat].reduce({ :a=>{:b=>{:c=>3 } } }) { |acum, key|
  acum.fetch(key) } rescue 4
  #=> 4
```

and if `args #=> []`, `[].empty?` is `true`, so the value of `default` is again returned:

```
[].empty? ? 4 : [].reduce({ :a=>{:b=>{:c=>3 } } }) { |acum, key|
  acum.fetch(key) } rescue 4
  #=> 4
```

Fortunately, we no longer have to deal with such nonsense as we were given [Hash#dig](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/Hash.html#method-i-dig) in Ruby 2.3.0, allowing us to write the following.

```
class Hash
  def get_value( default, *keys )
    keys.empty? ? default : dig(*keys) || default
  end
end

{ :a=>{:b=>{:c=>3 } } }.get_value(4, :a, :b, :c)
  #=> 3
{ :a=>{:b=>{:c=>3 } } }.get_value(4, :a, :b)
  #=> {:c=>3} 
{ :a=>{:b=>{:c=>3 } } }.get_value(4, :a, :b, :cat)
  #=> 4 
{ :a=>{:b=>{:c=>3 } } }.get_value(4)
  #=> 4
```

Note that the default receiver of `dig` is `self`.

<sup>1 Note that instead of `...args.reduce(self) { |acum, key| acum.fetch(key) } rescue default` the author of that code could have written `...args.reduce(self) { |acum, key| acum.fetch(key, default) }`. See [Hash#fetch](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/Hash.html#method-i-fetch).</sup>

Answer (score 1):

It assumes `self` is a nest of hashes, and treats `args` as a sequence of keys to dive deeper and deeper into that nest of hashes.

Answer (score 0):

`self` is the `config` hash itself.

`reduce` accepts an argument which is `self` (hence original `config` hash).

Then `accum` on first iteration will be assigned with that argument (which is original `config` hash).

On each iteration, the `accum` will be reassigned with the (nested) value for each key of `args`.

Answer (score 0):

Let's look at the following example instead.

```
config = {
  :files => { :mode => 0x777 },
  :name => "config"
}

[:files, :mode].reduce(config) { |hash, key|
  # The value for the current key, which can be another hash.
  newhash = hash.fetch(key)

  # Log each iteration here to see what's happening.
  # p newhash

  # Return the value for next iteration.
  newhash
}
```

The output is the HEX value `0x777`, which is converted by Ruby to the decimal `1911`.

In your example with `args.reduce(self)`, `self` is the initial value that is passed as the first argument to the block, which is the `config` hash itself. Array mixes in Enumerable, and that's where *reduce* comes from. More info here: http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Enumerable.html#method-i-reduce

---

For each iteration of *reduce*, the block variables contain the following values:

### Iteration 1

- `hash` contains `{ :files => { :mode => 0x777 }, :name => "config" }`; this is the *config* hash itself.
- `key` contains `:files`; the first item of the array.
- `newhash` contains `{:mode=>1911}`, which we return and becomes the first argument of the next iteration.

### Iteration 2

- `hash` contains `{:mode=>1911}` because we returned *newhash* in the previous iteration.
- `key` contains `:mode`; the second item of the array.
- `newhash` contains `1911`; the reduce iterations are done and this is the final value.